# Get the day of the week from HTML5 date input

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a datepicker from HTML5 date input to select a date for a web form. I have a requirement to show a warning message if the date is not a Monday. I am using JavaScript to check the date but it seems to not work. I have tried below to get the day of the week but it is not working.

```
var date = new Date(document.getElementById("txtStartDate"));
var day = date.getDay(); 
if (day == 1) alert('MONDAY!');
else if (day != 1) alert("NOT MONDAY");
```

Comment: Please explain "it seems to not work".

Comment: for monday its 0 btw.

Comment: It seems not to work means that it doesn't alert at all. Thanks for letting me know about 0 being a Monday.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript it's day numbering starts at `0`. So monday is actually `0` and `6` is saterday.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing the element's value, not the element itself to the `Date` constructor.

```
var date = new Date(document.getElementById("txtStartDate").value);
```

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click", function(e){
    const value = document.getElementById("date").value;
    const date = new Date(value);
    const day = date.getDay();
    if(day === 1){
        console.log("Monday");
    } else {
        console.log("Not Monday!");
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date">
<button>Submit</button>
```

Comment: In my browser, this only reports "Monday" if I pick a Sunday

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am using a function called dateCheck() in my code and I want this to do a check on change event. Can I just apply the event listener on a change event?

Comment: Got it to work by using document.getElementById("txtStartDate").value. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sunday === 0: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

Comment: @hev1 that's because you fixed it after I left that comment :)

Comment: @SpoonMeiser No, it was working before. It no longer works for me, but I decided to change it since it apparently works for the rest of you.